# Using an existing spreadsheet as a template PHPspreadsheet

Tags: phpspreadsheet

**Objective**

I want to use an existing Excel sheet, as a template to create an invoice.

- Cell styling, such as coloring have to be included
- An image (logo) has to be included
- Standard data such as company address has to be included

I've read something about cfspreadsheet, but I'm not entirely sure how to use it.

**Question A:**

Is there a way to use a template file? Or do you know any alternatives?

**Question B**

Is it possible to use $_POST data with this library?

**Example**

```
$data = $_POST['example'];

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', '$data');
```

Comment: Yes! Using PHPSpreadsheet you can load an existing spreadsheet as a template, populate cells in that with data, then save it again with a new filename

Comment: Data is whatever data you want to use, whether it comes from a POST request, or from a database or wherever

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not 100% sure, but according to PhpSpreadsheet's [doc](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/), you can read a local file (your pre-made template) with :

```php
$inputFileName = './sampleData/example1.xls';

/** Load $inputFileName to a Spreadsheet Object  **/
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
```

**Or in case you already know the file type (.xlsx or .xsl) :**

```php
$inputFileType = 'Xls'; // Xlsx - Xml - Ods - Slk - Gnumeric - Csv
$inputFileName = './sampleData/example1.xls';

/**  Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType  **/
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
/**  Load $inputFileName to a Spreadsheet Object  **/
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);
```

You can also wrap all of that in a try catch if you want.

Then you just have to make changes the same way you would populate a Spreadsheet you created, populating cells with data you get from pretty much where you want with php, examples :

- Classic variable `$foo = 'bar';`
- `$_GET` / `$_POST` / `$_REQUEST`
- From a Database