# Problem to organize xlsx file with PhpSpreadsheet Library

Tags: php, html, laravel, phpspreadsheet

I would like to create a xlsx file with php, however I have difficult to organize the document. In the general, I want to leave my xlsx file this way:
[xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUP7X.png)

But my file is this way:

[xlsx2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwcJo.png)

Someone can help me to organize the code?

Here is my code:

At first, I put the title.

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:D1');
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'LISTAGEM DE PENDÊNCIAS');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:D1')->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('5481eb');
```

And then, I organaize the column in the second line:

```
$sheet->getDefaultRowDimension()->setRowHeight(25);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(17);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(17);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(28);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(28);

$styleArray = array(
    'font'  => array(
        'bold'  => true,
        'color' => array('rgb' => 'FFFFFF'),
        'size'  => 18,
        'family' => 'Verdana',
    )
);

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);

foreach (range('A', 'D') as $columnID) {
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($columnID)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($columnID)->getAlignment()->setVertical('center');
}

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B2')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('left');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B3')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('left');

$styleArray = array(
    'borders' => array(
        'outline' => array(
            'borderStyle' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THIN,
            'color' => array('argb' => '000000'),
        ),
    ),
);

$styleArray2 = array(
    'borders' => array(
        'outline' => array(
            'borderStyle' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THIN,
            'color' => array('argb' => '000000'),
        ),
    ),
);

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:D1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);


$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2')->applyFromArray($styleArray2);
$sheet->setCellValue( 'A2', 'PROTOCOLO:');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2')->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('707070');

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B2')->applyFromArray($styleArray2);
$styleArray2 = array(
    'font'  => array(
        'bold'  => true,
        'color' => array('rgb' => 'FFFFFF'),
        'size'  => 12,
    )
);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B2:D2');
$sheet->setCellValue('B2', '2/2021');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B2')->applyFromArray($styleArray2);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B2')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('left');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B2:D2')->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('C4C0C0');
$sheet->getDefaultRowDimension()->setRowHeight(25);


$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A3')->applyFromArray($styleArray2);
$sheet->setCellValue( 'A3', 'CÓDIGO DO LOTE:');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A3')->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('707070');

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B3')->applyFromArray($styleArray2);
$styleArray2 = array(
    'font'  => array(
        'bold'  => true,
        'color' => array('rgb' => 'FFFFFF'),
        'size'  => 12,
    )
);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B3:D3');
$sheet->setCellValue('B3', '1234');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B3')->applyFromArray($styleArray2);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B3')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('left');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B3:D3')->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('C4C0C0');
$sheet->getDefaultRowDimension()->setRowHeight(25);
```

Here I wright the Veículos, Pendências and Status column:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A4:B4')->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('707070');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C4')->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('707070');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D4')->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('707070');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A4:B4');
$sheet->setCellValue('A4', 'VÍNCULO');
$sheet->setCellValue('C4', 'PENDÊNCIAS');
$sheet->setCellValue('D4', 'STATUS');
```

Here I finalize the code with the lasts informations:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A5:B5');
$sheet->setCellValue('A5', 'Leandro Benjamin Souza');
$sheet->setCellValue('C5', 'CPF');
$sheet->setCellValue('D5', 'Apto');

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A6:B6');
$sheet->setCellValue('A6', 'Leandro Benjamin Souza');
$sheet->setCellValue('C6', 'CPF');
$sheet->setCellValue('D6', 'Apto');

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A7:B7');
$sheet->setCellValue('A7', 'Leandro Benjamin Souza');
$sheet->setCellValue('C7', 'CPF');
$sheet->setCellValue('D7', 'Apto');

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet); //Instanciando uma nova planilha

$writer->save('Listagem de Protocolos com Pendencia.xlsx'); //salvando a planilha na extensão definida
```

Comment: Why don't you start off with an [already built & styled XLSX template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48803647/7376590) and just fill in the relevant data afterward?

Comment: because I need to put so many informations there

Comment: What do you mean by: *'...so many informations...'*? To begin with, it doesn't seem you have a lot of dynamic data.

Comment: Exactly, I will use a loop to put so many information's, that is why I want to do the code this way

Comment: Your post is quite some time so not sure you're still needing help or not. I see your result was already organized well in terms of merging. So your main issue is actually on the styling ? wording overflow ?